# Python: KenLM installation error

Tags: python-2.7, kenlm

I am installing KenLM on Python2.7 on Windows 7 64 bit with the following command:

```
pip install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
```

Error message:

```
 C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
    Collecting https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
      Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
    ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000373C2B0>, 'Connection to gith
    ub.com timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
      Downloading https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip (518kB)
        100% |################################| 522kB 7.3kB/s
    Installing collected packages: kenlm
      Running setup.py install for kenlm ... error
        Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
    , tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\phyukh~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-gny9pz-build
    \\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\
    r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:
    \users\phyukh~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-jpsst8-record\install-record.txt --single
    -version-externally-managed --compile:
        'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        running install
        running build
        running build_ext
        building 'kenlm' extension
        creating build
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\util
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\lm
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\util\double-conversion
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\python
        C:\Users\PhyuKhaing\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for P
    ython\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I. -Ic:\pyth
    on27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tputil\bit_packing.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    \Release\util\bit_packing.obj -O3 -DNDEBUG -DKENLM_MAX_ORDER=6 -std=c++11
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
        bit_packing.cc
        .\util/bit_packing.hh(30) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'st
    dint.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Users\\PhyuKhaing\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Mic
    rosoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit sta
    tus 2

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
    \users\\phyukh~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-gny9pz-build\\setup.py';f=getattr(to
    kenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();ex
    ec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\phyukh~1\appdata\
    local\temp\pip-jpsst8-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-mana
    ged --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\phyukh~1\appdata\local\temp\
    pip-gny9pz-build\
```

Comment: Have a look at the discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1598). Update your question with regard to the bash location.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `python -m pip install pypi-kenlm`